# sort a stack using temporary stack python

Tags: python, stack

Actually I cant understand this code. We create a stack and append values in it and popping first element. Then this condition len(ts)!=0 is confusing. Initially we didnt append any values to ts then how this condition is satisfied.

```
def sortstack(stack):
        ts = createStack()
        while len(stack) != 0:
            temp = stack.pop()
            while len(ts) != 0 and int(top(ts))>int(temp):
                stack.append(ts.pop())
            ts.append(temp)
        return ts
def createStack():
    stack=[]
    return stack
def top(stack):
    return stack[len(stack)-1]
stack=createStack()
stack.append(10)
stack.append(23)
stack.append(5)
stack.append(80)
stack.append(6)
```

Comment: Look at what happens *after* the inner loop, while still in the *outer* loop.

Comment: can you elaborate pls

Comment: In the first run, you 1) enter the outer `while` loop, 2) don't enter the inner `while` loop, 3) append `temp` to `ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Its skips first run of the loop (because initially we didn't append any values to "ts") and append first element to "ts" in "ts.append(temp)". After that on second run of the loop its enters in second while loop

Comment: if top element in ts is< than temp means we should pop it and add it to stack right. But the condition is reverse here?